# Upload File not uploading in server storage

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is it true, when we serialize a image file using serializer, serializer doesnt upload file to media, it just confirm that file is a image file and change the value in model.
So, i need function below in view.py for write file to my server storage file.

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open(f'media/{f}', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

example model file

```
class Product(models.Model):
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    availability = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=1)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', blank=True, null=True)
```

example serializer

```
class UpdateProductSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Did you try to adding MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' before this ?

Comment: Yes, i add both in settings root

Comment: And i can upload the images when use admin view